# How can I get the content of a tag in HTML with a given attribute using regular expressions?

Tags: php, html, regex

I'd hoped to get all of the content between the tag `a` with `class` `bc-de fg` in a HTML file, like this:

```
<a class="bc-de fg"> XXXXXXXXXXXXX </a>
```

So I wrote the following regular expression:

```
$regexp = “<a\wclass="bc\wde">(.*?)<\/a>”
```

This does't work. I'm new to regular expressions, so I am trying to get more practice.

How can I correct this regular expression?

Comment: Cthulhu here... Use a DOM parser.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/78845

Answer (score 0):

Try something like `$regex = ":<a class="bc-de fg">(.*?)</a>:mi";`

- I used the delimeter `:` So I don't have to escape forward slashes all the time
- `.` Matches any single character except line break characters \r and \n.
- `*?` Repeats the previous item zero or more times.

Here's a simple [cheatsheet](http://www.addedbytes.com/download/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet-v2/png/) you might find useful.

Answer (score 0):

It is considered a bad practice to `regex` over html, or any nested structures. Use `DOM` instead.

Your problem in regex is the escape characters (put the regex string between single quotes). And you also have no starting and closing regex characters (`#...#` or `\...\`).

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be a comment or deleted altogether.

Comment: Yeah I know, but I hope to use reg ex to do so...

Comment: This edit is much more like an answer ☺

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$str  = '<a class="bc-de fg">Testing</a>';

preg_match('/<a class="bc\-de\s*fg">(?P<link>.*)<\/a>/',$str,$matches);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($matches);
```

You will get link in `$link = $matches['link'];`

This will give you more accurate results :

`preg_match('/<a.*class="bc\-de\s*fg".*>\s*(?P<link>.*)\s*<\/a>/',$str,$matches);`

Comment: Why can I use a whitespace directly? Should't I use \w?

Comment: You can use white space but \s is the regular exp pattern for space, as you need all the text in anchor tag I used .* instead of \w

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$regexp = '/<a class="bc-de fg">(.*)<\/a>/';
preg_match_all($regexp, $subject, $matches);
```

You answer will be in `$matches` .  It should work int the scenario you just mentioned. But if the case is, if order of attributes changes or more classes are assigned, this regex wont work. Best way to do this is to use DOM instead of using regex.

Answer (score 0):

Try `[^(<a\W*class="bc\-de fg"\W*>)+(</a>)+]` You can use the not `^` operator .